# CPU Info - speed - manufacturer

Tags: java, android

I basically have the same question as here :

[How to find CPU load of any Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714396/how-to-find-cpu-load-of-any-android-device-programmatically)

This question was discussed here with many comments but none is anywhere near the solution.

I have tried them all, implemented and tried them on mu Android device. None give the information like on this screenshot, the CPU name (qualcomm , mediatek...) , cpu clock speed, gpu information too...

Did anyone found a solution to this ? How does the cpu-z team do it ?

Comment: See this Github repo: https://github.com/kamgurgul/cpu-info/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kgurgul/cpuinfo/features/information/cpu/CpuInfoViewModel.kt

Comment: you need to create a database of cpunames for yourself. cpuz fetches cpuname from their own db

Comment: @SaurabhThorat , thank you, but the guy HAD to use Kotlin :(