# React-Native: get MORE device information ( ANDROID & IOS )

Tags: android, ios, react-native

As we know, there are few RN libraries, that working with device sensors.
They can work with GPS, magnetometer, accelerometer, etc.

BUT I can't find any libraries, that can get device temperature( CPU, accumulator, etc ), proximity, CPU / GPU load, accumulator charge level, etc. I.e, more heavy information.

What libraries you are use to get this data ?

Especially, I'm interested for accumulator params ( charge level, temp )

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714396/how-to-find-cpu-load-of-any-android-device-programmatically. Here you can get a native method, create native wrapper on this and use in react native where you want.

Comment: By `accumulator` do you mean the battery?

Comment: @10101010, sure. Internal phone accumulator( battery )

Comment: There is probably no single react-native library which can get you all those details.https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info comes close. If you want more native level features, you could write android code that communicates with react-native